# How do I find my Ethereum Contract Number

Tags: accounts, internal-transactions

Sorry to everybody, as this probably sounds like a silly question, I'm new to all of this and I'm struggling to find my contract number.
I've sent a lot of USDC to my ETH wallet, which never arrived and thought I lost all of it.
looking into it, I've found out I have to verify, I thought that must be my wallet address, I looked into more and needed a contract number to verify my account.
How do I find my contract number?
Is the process different for a new wallet?
Once I verify my account will my USDC go into my wallet?
If anybody can give me an answer to this, I will greatly appreciate it
Thank you.

Comment: Just share the address which has your USDCs

Comment: What wallet are you using to receive USDC? To receive USDC you only the your wallet address. You mention "to verify my account".. Can you clarify what does that mean?